# Listener not working on Grid Panel - Ext JS

Tags: javascript, events, extjs, grid

This is probably something incredibly simple I'm missing, but I can't figure out why my listener won't work here.

I've defined a grid with a few colums below:

```
    ...
    {header: 'Privacy', dataIndex: 'PRIVACY_INDICATOR', flex: 3, tdCls: 'grid_cell'},
    {header: 'Lineage', dataIndex: 'popup', renderer: renderPopupIcon, flex: 1, tdCls: 'pop_cell', id: 'lineage_button',
        listeners:  {
            cellclick: function(record) {
                alert('cell has been clicked');
            }
         }
}
```

I have tried everything, but I can't seem to get the alert to fire.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well `cellclick` event is available to grid and not to column. You have added `cellclick` listener on column where you should add it to grid. See below example, you can run it on column's [Ext Doc](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column) Code Editor, simply copy and paste it and select `Live Preview` :

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId:'employeeStore',
    fields:['firstname', 'lastname', 'seniority', 'dep', 'hired'],
    data:[
        {firstname:"Michael", lastname:"Scott", seniority:7, dep:"Management", hired:"01/10/2004"},
        {firstname:"Dwight", lastname:"Schrute", seniority:2, dep:"Sales", hired:"04/01/2004"},
        {firstname:"Jim", lastname:"Halpert", seniority:3, dep:"Sales", hired:"02/22/2006"},
        {firstname:"Kevin", lastname:"Malone", seniority:4, dep:"Accounting", hired:"06/10/2007"},
        {firstname:"Angela", lastname:"Martin", seniority:5, dep:"Accounting", hired:"10/21/2008"}
    ]
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Column Demo',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('employeeStore'),
    columns: [
        {text: 'First Name',  dataIndex:'firstname'},
        {text: 'Last Name',  dataIndex:'lastname'},
        {text: 'Hired Month',  dataIndex:'hired', xtype:'datecolumn', format:'M'},
        {text: 'Department (Yrs)', xtype:'templatecolumn', tpl:'{dep} ({seniority})'}
    ],
    listeners: {
        cellclick: function(view, td, cellIndex, record, tr, rowIndex, e, eOpts) {
            Ext.Msg.alert('Selected Record', 'Name : ' + record.get('firstname') + ' ' + record.get('lastname'));
        }
    },
    width: 400,
    forceFit: true,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

### UPDATE :

If you want to capture event only for particular cell/column, you can use `cellIndex` property which is one of among `cellclick` function's argument. For e.g. : you want to show alert when user clicks on `Lineage` column and that column is 4th column, you will use below code :

```
cellclick: function(view, td, cellIndex, record, tr, rowIndex, e, eOpts) {
    // if clicked on cell 4, show popup otherwise ignore
    if(cellIndex == 3) { // cellIndex starts from 0
        Ext.Msg.alert('Selected Record', 'Name : ' + record.get('firstname') + ' ' + record.get('lastname'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Which version of ExtJS are you using? It is noticed that in certain versions (4.1.1 for sure) `cellclick` event is not being fired at all (see the comments in the [offical documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-event-cellclick)). If that's that case, try with `itemclick` event. Another reason could be that you are catching this event with

```
cellclick: function(record) {..
```

and you should with

```
cellclick: function(field, td, cellIndex, record, tr, rowIndex, e, eOpts) {..
```